# Dart null-safety breaks Future<bool> anonymous method?

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror, future, dart-null-safety

Prior to migrating to null safety this worked. This is a user login verification method.

```
Future<bool> loginValidate() async {
    final String dir = await getDocDir(); //getting documents directory
    try {
      await File('$dir/$_userLoginString.json')
          .readAsString()
          .then((String contents) {
        final json = jsonDecode(contents) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final user = PersonLoginJson.fromJson(json);
        if (_userPasswordString != user.password) {
          //invalid password
          return Future<bool>.value(false);
        }
      });
    } on FileSystemException {
      //invalid username
      return Future<bool>.value(false);
    } catch (e) {
      return Future<bool>.value(false);
    }
    //success
    return Future<bool>.value(true);
  }
```

This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO9If.png) occurs when the app is being built.

I believe it has to do with the anonymous function argument within the .then() method.

Comment: Your callback function neglects to return a value along all code paths.  Therefore, it implicitly returns `null` along if the `if` condition isn't met, and a `null` return value is unexpected.  Fix your code to return values along all code paths.  Also, it's inconsistent to mix `await` and `then`; just use `await`, which would have made your problem more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the `await` function and also need to set the `true` value to make it work:

```dart
return await File('$dir/$_userLoginString.json')
          .readAsString()
          .then((String contents) {
        final json = jsonDecode(contents) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final user = PersonLoginJson.fromJson(json);
        if (_userPasswordString != user.password) {
          //invalid password
          return Future<bool>.value(false);
        }

        //Also need this code as it will return null if not set
        return Future<bool>.value(true);
      });
```

---

**BETTER WAY I THINK:**

Let's change this code:

```dart
await File('$dir/$_userLoginString.json')
          .readAsString()
          .then((String contents) {
        final json = jsonDecode(contents) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final user = PersonLoginJson.fromJson(json);
        if (_userPasswordString != user.password) {
          //invalid password
          return Future<bool>.value(false);
        }
      });
```

to this:

```dart
String contents = await File('$dir/$_userLoginString.json').readAsString();
final json = jsonDecode(contents) as Map<String, dynamic>;
final user = PersonLoginJson.fromJson(json);
if (_userPasswordString != user.password) {
   //invalid password
   return Future<bool>.value(false);
}
```

Then it will be easier to debug your code now.

Comment: This works, solved. The Try - Catch block is still needed around the first statement though.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
if (_userPasswordString != user.password) {
  //invalid password
  return Future<bool>.value(false);
} else {
  return Future<bool>.value(true);   // <--- here needed
}
```

Comment: This would have fixed it but I had logic outside of the .then() scope which would have died.

Comment: @Demiurge logic outside is for exception case, it will still live if the api get exception.